# Bootstrap clock face plugin conflict with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap clock face plugin for time picker. I have also used jquery ui. I am having the problem that for some reason when I include jquery UI then the clock face does not work. When I remove jquery ui library clock face works properly. There is no error in console or there is no other javascript error.

I have tried adding the jquery ui library before, after the bootstrap.min.js but of no use.

Initializing clock face in this way

```
$('.custom-clockface-input').clockface();
```

Is there any way to fix this issue ?? Please Help me..

Comment: give us a fiddle with the error which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use different version of Jquery and try to use like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.custom-clockface-input').clockface();
    });
</script>
```